# What is the Javascript "map" equivalent in Dart?

Tags: javascript, dart

I'm new to Dart and I noticed that the method `map` is not working the same as in Javascript.

I'm trying to convert a list of dynamic to a list of object.

In Javascript, this would work:

```
List<BoxType> boxTypes = data["boxTypes"].map((dynamic boxType) => BoxType.fromDynamic(boxType));
```

But in Dart, I got this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<BoxType>')
```

I saw that I could do a `.toList()` at the end like this:

```
List<BoxType> boxTypes = data["boxTypes"].map((dynamic boxType) => BoxType.fromDynamic(boxType)).toList();
```

But it generates this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<BoxType>')
```

So, what should I use instead of `map` ?

Edit: For now, that's what I'm doing, it's a bit ugly but it works well

```
for (var i = 0; i < data["boxTypes"].length; i++) {
  boxTypes.add(BoxType.fromDynamic(data["boxTypes"][i]));
}
```

Comment: isn't it because of 
... .map((dynamic boxType) =>...
shouldn't it be BoxType boxType ?

Comment: I map from a list of dynamic, that's why the parameter is dynamic. I return a `BoxType`, so I don't understand the issue here

Comment: Do you get the same error if you don't give the type of the map arg as in `data["boxTypes"].map((boxType) => BoxType.fromDynamic(boxType)).toList();`?

Comment: I just tried and it returns the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `dynamic` in your `map`, not `BoxType` - the error says that `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of 'List<BoxType>'`, so just fixing this should work:

```
List<BoxType> boxTypes = data["boxTypes"].map((BoxType boxType) => BoxType.fromDynamic(boxType)).toList();
```

Comment: `data["boxTypes"]` is a dynamic object, that's why I use `.fromDynamic` in the return. If I do as you say, I got this error: `_TypeError (type '(BoxType) => BoxType' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f')`

Answer (score 0):

This code runs without problems:

```
void main() {
  List dynamicList = [1, 2, "hello", true];

  Map<String, List> map = {'boxTypes': dynamicList};

  // make sure to check for null with ?. and reeturn an empty list if null
  List<BoxType> boxes = map["boxTypes"]?.map((box) => BoxType.fromDynamic(box))?.toList() ?? [];

  // same, but a little shorter
  //List<BoxType> boxes = map["boxTypes"]?.map(BoxType.fromDynamic)?.toList() ?? [];


  print(boxes);
}

class BoxType {
  String type;
  BoxType(this.type);

  static BoxType fromDynamic(value) {
    if (value is String) {
      return BoxType(value);
    }
    return BoxType(value?.toString() ?? "no value");
  }

  String toString() => "BoxType{type=${type}}";
}
```

If I change the type of `map` to `Map<String, dynamic>`, however, I get the same error as you...

Can you verify the type of your map declares the values as being `List`?

The Dart compiler should pick this up as a type-checking error, but that doesn't seem to be happening until runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot change the type of map, it's a dynamic coming from a HTTP call. To me, it looks like a bug in Dart, the return of the map returns a BoxType object, it shouldn't see it as a dynamic anymore.

Comment: But what's the type of the `data` object?

Comment: A dynamic, which represents an object with several properties, including a list of BoxType

Comment: When you type something as dynamic, Dart will let you call methods on it that only fail at runtime if the type is wrong... Don't use dynamic directly, cast it to the type you think it is, checking first with `if (obj is X)` to avoid errors.